# Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a simple slider, but I have I this problem:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
```

This is my code:

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll("div");

for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){  
    div[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.remove("active");
        div[i+1].classList.add("active");
    }
}
```

Can any one help me please ?

Comment: When you get to the last element `i+1` is out of bounds.

Comment: @tmslnz: Answers do not go in the comments section, thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this might occur because i is scoped to the outer function, so it'll always be set to the max value for i. Because of this, `div[i + 1]` will always be undefined. What you could do is:

```
div[i].onclick = function(idx) {
  this.classList.remove("active");
  if(idx < div.length - 1) div[idx + 1].classList.add("active");
}.bind(div[i], i);
```

What bind does is it takes a snapshot of the values of variables that you are passing to functions, as well as a value for "this". The value for "this" comes first, then arguments for the function follow it. It then returns the function it was called on, with some subset of its arguments bound to the values you provided. Any arguments that were not bound can be provided by the caller, but all bound arguments must come before arguments supplied by the caller.

Comment: thanks very much it works well now i was searching 5 days for the solution
thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help :)