# Making elements appear and disappear loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have a problem with the below code. This is supposed to return the section on the page that has an id, so I can then remove the id and give it to another section that is invisible, making the new one visible. These are tied to a click eventhandler. What happens though, is that the next window appears for a fraction of a second and then disappears. I need it to stay, and on the next click on the button the next section should appear etc.
I believe it might have something to do with the loop, but I can't figure out what. What am I missing?

Edit: I added everything HTML, CSS JS now so everything is there.

JS

```
var sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");

var btns = document.querySelector("input[type='submit']");

//* 
This part should switch to the next ingredient selection
*// 
function next(){
    var i=0;
    while (i+1 <= sections.length) {
if (sections[i].hasAttribute ("id")) {
        sections[i].removeAttribute("id");
        i=i+1;
        sections[i].setAttribute("id","visible");
        break;
} }}

btns.addEventListener('click', next);
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pete's Pizzeria</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script|Mr+Dafoe|Nothing+You+Could+Do|Yellowtail|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="mainh1">Pete's pizzeria</h1>
        <main>
        <section id="visible">
            <header>
                <h1>Choose your size!</h1>
            </header>
            <form>
                <p>Personal<input type="radio" name="size" value="personal" checked><span class="price" data-price="6">$6.00</span> </p>
                <p>Medium<input type="radio" name="size" value="medium"><span class="price" value=10>$10.00</span> </p>
                <p>Large<input type="radio" name="size" value="large"><span class="price" data-price="14">$14.00</span></p>
                <p>Extra Large <input type="radio" name="size" value="extralarge"><span class="price" data-price="16">$16.00</span></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Next">
            </form>
        </section>
        <section>
            <header>
                <h1>Nice to meat you!</h1>
                <p>The first meat item is complimentary. All additional meat items cost $1 each.</p>
            </header>
            <form>
                <p>Pepperoni<input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="pepperoni" checked></p>
                <p>Sausage<input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="sausage" ></p>
                <p>Canadian Bacon<input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="canadianBacon" ></p>
                <p>Ground Beef <input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="groundBeef"></p>
                <p>Anchovy <input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="anchovy"></p>
                <p>Chicken <input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="chicken"></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Next">
            </form>
        </section>
         <section>
             <header>
                 <h1>How cheesy<br>are you?</h1>
             </header>
            <form>
                <p>Regular<input type="radio" name="cheese" value="regularcheese" checked></p>
                <p>No cheese<input type="radio" name="cheese" value="nocheese" ></p>
                <p>Extra Cheese <span data-price="3">(+$3.00)</span><input type="radio" name="cheese" value="extracheese"></p>             <input type="submit" value="Next">
            </form>
        </section>
        <section>
            <header>
                <h1>Everyone bites<br>the crust</h1>
            </header>
            <form>
                <p>Plain Crust<input type="radio" name="crust" value="plainCrust" checked></p>
                <p>Garlic Butter Crust<input type="radio" name="crust" value="garlicButterCrust" ></p>
                <p>Cheese Stuffed Crust <span data-price="3">(+$3.00)</span><input type="radio" name="crust" value="cheeseStuffedCrust" ></p>
                <p>Spicy Crust<input type="radio" name="crust" value="spicyCrust"></p>
                <p>House Special Crust<input type="radio" name="crust" value="houseSpecialCrust"></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Next">
            </form>
        </section>
        <section>
            <header>
                <h1>Our pizzas are saucy</h1>
            </header>
            <form>
                <p>Marinara sauce<input type="radio" name="sauce" value="marinaraSauce" checked></p>
                <p>White sauce<input type="radio" name="sauce" value="garlicButterCrust" ></p>
                <p>Barbeque sauce<input type="radio" name="sauce" value="BBQsauce" ></p>
                <p>No Sauce<input type="radio" name="sauce" value="noSauce"></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Next">
            </form>
        </section>
        <section>
            <form>

                <header>
                    <h1>Always eat your veggies</h1>
                    The first type of veggie is complimentary. All additional veggie items cost $1 each.
                </header>

                <p>Tomatoes<input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="tomatoes" checked></p>
                <p>Onions<input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="onions" ></p>
                <p>Olives<input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="olives" ></p>
                <p>Green Peppers<input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="greenPeppers"></p>
                <p>Mushrooms<input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="mushrooms"></p>
                <p>Pineapple <input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="pineapple"></p>
                <p>Spinach <input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="spinach"></p>
                <p>Jalapeno <input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="jalapeno"></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Next">
            </form>
        </section>
        <section id="tally">
            <h1>The bottom line</h1>
            <p>testPizzaIngredient <span>$10</span></p>
            <p>testPizzaIngredient <span>$10</span></p>
            <p>testPizzaIngredient <span>$10</span></p>
            <p>testPizzaIngredient <span>$10</span></p>
            <p>testPizzaIngredient <span>$10</span></p>
            <p>testPizzaIngredient <span>$10</span></p>
            <p>testPizzaIngredient <span>$10</span></p>
        </section>
</main>


        <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0 0 auto auto;
    background-image: url(images/food-pizza-box-chalkboard.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top; 
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
    }

/*
==============================================================
Pete's pizzera title
==============================================================
*/
#mainh1 {
    font-family: 'Nothing You Could Do', cursive;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    left: 3rem;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ffffff;
}
/*
==============================================================
The box with the content
==============================================================
*/
section {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top:0 0;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    margin-top: 8rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(232, 232, 232,0.5);
    width: 15rem;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: none;}

/*
==============================================================
The class that will hide all boxes unless the person clicks on next, in which case the next is going to appear.
==============================================================
*/

#visible {
    display: block;
}

/*The title of the box*/
h1 {
    font-family: 'Nothing You Could Do', cursive;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    margin:0;
}

/*
==============================================================
aligning the check and radio buttons vertically
==============================================================
*/
input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
}
/*
==============================================================
aligning the prices vertically
==============================================================
*/
span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 4rem;
}
/*
==============================================================
line-spacing of paragraphs in the forms
==============================================================
*/

form p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0.5rem;
}



/*
==============================================================
Formatting of the "Next" button
==============================================================
*/
input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0.25rem;
}
/*
==============================================================
The box with the content
==============================================================
*/
#tally {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 15rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(232, 232, 232,0.5);
    width: 15rem;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
    }

#tally h1 {
    top: 2rem;
}

#tally p {
margin: 0.3rem;
}
```

Comment: This is not how you want to handle this I believe..... You use the id attribute to identify your element. Then use the 'display' styling to hide/reveal it. Or use a class. It most likely is disappearing because you have no styling for 'not-that-id' elements. Set in your CSS: #section-id .visible{ display: block;} #section-id{display:none;}, then you add remove visible class from the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("submit");

//console.log(btns);
function next(){
  var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section-card');
    //console.log(sections);
  for(var i = 0; i < sections.length - 1; i++){
if (sections[i].classList.contains('visible')) {
        //sections[i].removeAttribute("id");
        sections[i].classList.remove('visible');
        
        //sections[i].setAttribute("id","visible");
        sections[i+1].classList.add('visible');
        break;
} }}

for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', next);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0 0 auto auto;
    background-image: url(images/food-pizza-box-chalkboard.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top; 
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
    }

/*
==============================================================
Pete's pizzera title
==============================================================
*/
#mainh1 {
    font-family: 'Nothing You Could Do', cursive;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    left: 3rem;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ffffff;
}
/*
==============================================================
The box with the content
==============================================================
*/
.section-card {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top:0 0;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    margin-top: 8rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(232, 232, 232,0.5);
    width: 15rem;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: none;}

/*
==============================================================
The class that will hide all boxes unless the person clicks on next, in which case the next is going to appear.
==============================================================
*/
.section-card.visible{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top:0 0;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-top: 8rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(232, 232, 232,0.5);
  width: 15rem;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: block;}
}

/*The title of the box*/
h1 {
    font-family: 'Nothing You Could Do', cursive;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    margin:0;
}

/*
==============================================================
aligning the check and radio buttons vertically
==============================================================
*/
input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
}
/*
==============================================================
aligning the prices vertically
==============================================================
*/
span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 4rem;
}
/*
==============================================================
line-spacing of paragraphs in the forms
==============================================================
*/

form p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0.5rem;
}



/*
==============================================================
Formatting of the "Next" button
==============================================================
*/
.submit {
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0.25rem;
}
/*
==============================================================
The box with the content
==============================================================
*/
#tally {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 15rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(232, 232, 232,0.5);
    width: 15rem;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
    }

#tally h1 {
    top: 2rem;
}

#tally p {
margin: 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
        <h1 id="mainh1">Pete's pizzeria</h1>
        <main>
        <div class="section-card visible">
            <header>
                <h1>Choose your size!</h1>
            </header>
                <p>Personal<input type="radio" name="size" value="personal" checked><span class="price" data-price="6">$6.00</span> </p>
                <p>Medium<input type="radio" name="size" value="medium"><span class="price" value=10>$10.00</span> </p>
                <p>Large<input type="radio" name="size" value="large"><span class="price" data-price="14">$14.00</span></p>
                <p>Extra Large <input type="radio" name="size" value="extralarge"><span class="price" data-price="16">$16.00</span></p>
                <button class="submit">Next</button>
            
        </div>
        <div class="section-card">
            <header>
                <h1>Nice to meat you!</h1>
                <p>The first meat item is complimentary. All additional meat items cost $1 each.</p>
            </header>
                <p>Pepperoni<input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="pepperoni" checked></p>
                <p>Sausage<input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="sausage" ></p>
                <p>Canadian Bacon<input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="canadianBacon" ></p>
                <p>Ground Beef <input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="groundBeef"></p>
                <p>Anchovy <input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="anchovy"></p>
                <p>Chicken <input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="chicken"></p>
                <button class="submit">Next</button>
           
        </div>
         <div class="section-card">
             <header>
                 <h1>How cheesy<br>are you?</h1>
             </header>
                <p>Regular<input type="radio" name="cheese" value="regularcheese" checked></p>
                <p>No cheese<input type="radio" name="cheese" value="nocheese" ></p>
                <p>Extra Cheese <span data-price="3">(+$3.00)</span><input type="radio" name="cheese" value="extracheese"></p> 
           <button class="submit">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div class="section-card">
            <header>
                <h1>Everyone bites<br>the crust</h1>
            </header>
                <p>Plain Crust<input type="radio" name="crust" value="plainCrust" checked></p>
                <p>Garlic Butter Crust<input type="radio" name="crust" value="garlicButterCrust" ></p>
                <p>Cheese Stuffed Crust <span data-price="3">(+$3.00)</span><input type="radio" name="crust" value="cheeseStuffedCrust" ></p>
                <p>Spicy Crust<input type="radio" name="crust" value="spicyCrust"></p>
                <p>House Special Crust<input type="radio" name="crust" value="houseSpecialCrust"></p>
                <button class="submit">Next</button>
            
        </div>
        <div class="section-card">
            <header>
                <h1>Our pizzas are saucy</h1>
            </header>
                <p>Marinara sauce<input type="radio" name="sauce" value="marinaraSauce" checked></p>
                <p>White sauce<input type="radio" name="sauce" value="garlicButterCrust" ></p>
                <p>Barbeque sauce<input type="radio" name="sauce" value="BBQsauce" ></p>
                <p>No Sauce<input type="radio" name="sauce" value="noSauce"></p>
                <button class="submit">Next</button>
            
        </div>
        <div class="section-card">
            

                <header>
                    <h1>Always eat your veggies</h1>
                    The first type of veggie is complimentary. All additional veggie items cost $1 each.
                </header>

                <p>Tomatoes<input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="tomatoes" checked></p>
                <p>Onions<input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="onions" ></p>
                <p>Olives<input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="olives" ></p>
                <p>Green Peppers<input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="greenPeppers"></p>
                <p>Mushrooms<input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="mushrooms"></p>
                <p>Pineapple <input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="pineapple"></p>
                <p>Spinach <input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="spinach"></p>
                <p>Jalapeno <input type="checkbox" name="veggies" value="jalapeno"></p>
            <button class="submit">Next</button>
            
        </div>
        <div id="tally">
            <h1>The bottom line</h1>
            <p>testPizzaIngredient <span>$10</span></p>
            <p>testPizzaIngredient <span>$10</span></p>
            <p>testPizzaIngredient <span>$10</span></p>
            <p>testPizzaIngredient <span>$10</span></p>
            <p>testPizzaIngredient <span>$10</span></p>
            <p>testPizzaIngredient <span>$10</span></p>
            <p>testPizzaIngredient <span>$10</span></p>
        </div>
</main>
```

Updated with no JQuery

Here is a basic example of hiding and displaying elements on button click. I utilized opacity for transitions. You can just use display: block and display: none if you just want simple display/hide.

NEW UPDATE: (Based on entire code posted)
First of all, there is a problem with your form. It errors out on clicking next (which is why your sections disappear) because it wants a POST request. I changed the sections to divs, got rid of the forms, and changed input submits to .

You had a potentially infinite loop with your while statement, if the if statement inside is never entered, your loop will never stop, changed to a for loop to ensure it will stop.

You were not grabbing the sections again on the next button click (which causes the infinite loop mentioned above because no sections have the visible id). Now, you grab the sections every time a button is clicked.

Changed your removing and adding 'id' to removing and adding a class. Again, highly advise against changing css based on removing and adding an Id....

You also were not binding the click event to every button, just the first one, the for loop through the buttons now binds a click event to all the buttons. If you run my example now, it goes through all of your cards.

Comment: Thank you, but I am supposed to solve this problem without jQuery for now.

Comment: Updated with no JQuery and opacity transitions for better looking effects. (You cannot transition the display property).

Comment: Thanks. Now, I see that this is working, but since I am learning Javascript at the moment, can you point out to me maybe why my solution didn't work? Like are there things that I cannot do with element selectors but can do with class/id selectors?

Comment: I updated my answer to include some explanation. Hopefully it clears stuff up

Comment: Actually the only CSS the #id='visible' had was display: block. The rest of the styling was for the <section> element, which applied to all sections so they are consistent.
Now I tried to implement your solution, but it still gives me the same error message.
One detail I want to add. I have several windows overlapping, and my "button" is an input element type="submit" and part of a form. So I have actually a separate button for every window.

Comment: I have added my new code that I wanted to base on yours to the end of my original post. Why would it think that the sections[i] is undefined?

Comment: I just manually put all lines of the loop into the console, and it was working... I am just getting more and more confused.

Comment: I am pretty sure this now comes from getting sections[i+1]. You are looping i from 0 to sections.length - 1. So what happens when i = sections.length - 1? That is the last element of your sections array. So when you try to do sections[i+1], it is grabbing something undefined (outside of your array). If you want to do it that way, set your for loop to `i < sections.length - 1`, this will stop i at sections.length - 2, so i+1 is sections.length -1 (your last element), then your loop stops.

Comment: The script should run on the first few elements of the array anyway, shouldn't it? I know that there is a ceiling, but I just wanted to get it to run before I made these kinds of adjustments. I tried your change, but it didn't change anything. My first goal here now, is to figure out why it doesn't even do the first switch of the window. The first visible window is sections[0], so after button click, the sections[1] should appear.

Comment: Don't use Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('section')), document.getElementsByClassName('section') is already returning an array of all elements with class 'section'. That threw an error when I tried it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160649/discussion-between-krisztian-toth-and-tyler-dahle).

Comment: I have the idea it could have something to do with scoping, but I don't know all the rules about it yet. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930056/cannot-read-property-classlist-of-undefined]

Comment: I have just added the onclick event to document.activeElement. When I click a checkbox now in the window, it does switch to the next window.

Comment: Alright, so you are getting more of the behavior you are after now?

Comment: No the activeElement I only tried to try and eliminate if there is something with the loop or the button. I am stuck. Just don't know what I am missing.
Current state: The window switches to the next one for a very short time, and then back.

Comment: Updated again with your code working as you want. Again, you can utilize transition and opacity instead of display:none/display:block if you want some nice little fade-in/fade-out animations.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! It is really appreaciated. I am gonna go and go through step by step to learn what I missed.

Comment: I am not sure how to fix the post request form issue, haven't looked into it much. That will probably have to be another question post, if you need forms and submit buttons, that is